# Getting data from Repository to Viewmodel without passing observer to the activity

Tags: java, android

Why i should pass the LiveData to the activity to get the value of **allQuestions**. I am a little bit confused.

I tried to get the List of allQuestions in **QuestionViewModel** from the repo directly but it didn't work.

**This is what's in my brain.**

```
public class QuestionViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

private Repository repo;
private List<QuestionModel> allQuestions;

public QuestionViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
    repo = new Repository(application);
    allQuestions = repo.getAllQuestions().getValue(); //This line did not work for me (︶︹︺)
}}
```

***What i did do to get it work.***

**ViewModel**

```
public class QuestionViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

private Repository repo;
private LiveData<List<QuestionModel>> allQuestions;
public List<QuestionModel> CurrentListOfQues;


public QuestionViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
    repo = new Repository(application);
    allQuestions = repo.getAllQuestions();
}

public LiveData<List<QuestionModel>> GetAllQues() {
    if (allQuestions == null) {
        allQuestions = new LiveData<List<QuestionModel>>() {
            @Override
            public void observe(@NonNull LifecycleOwner owner, @NonNull Observer<? super List<QuestionModel>> observer) {
                super.observe(owner, observer);
            }
        };
    }
    return allQuestions;
}

public void setCurrent(List<QuestionModel> CurrentListOfQues) {
        if (this.CurrentListOfQues == null) {
            this.CurrentListOfQues = CurrentListOfQues;
        }
}
```

**Question Activity**

```
QVM = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(QuestionViewModel.class);

QVM.GetAllQues().observe(this, new Observer<List<QuestionModel>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<QuestionModel> allQuestions) {
            QVM.setCurrent(allQuestions);
        }
    });
```

Is this the right way to get the list in my viewmodel? Why `allQuestions = repo.getAllQuestions().getValue();` is always `null`

Comment: LiveData must be bounded to a lifecycle observer (activity/fragment)

Comment: Ok, but is it okay to send it back to the ViewModel? Is this an efficient way?